# Copying data table to table without column specification in query

Tags: mysql

I have a problem to copy data from one table to another table. There is lots of solution found but my problem is something different. I have two tables `sku` and `shipping_skudetails`. I have to copy data form `shipping_skudetails` to `sku`, for this m doing this,

```
INSERT INTO test.sku 
    SELECT SkuDetailsId as id, 
           sku, 
           seller_id as sellerID, 
           itemName as name, 
           itemLength as length, 
           itemWidth as width, 
           itemHeight as height, 
           itemWeight as weight, 
           modeType_id as mode
    FROM testdb.shipping_skudetails;

+----+---------+----------+-------------+--------+-------+--------+--------+------+
| id | sku     | sellerID | name        | length | width | height | weight | mode |
+----+---------+----------+-------------+--------+-------+--------+--------+------+
|  1 | Sample  |        1 | SampleItem  |      1 |     1 |      1 |      1 |    1 |
|  2 | Sample  |        2 | Sample1     |      1 |     1 |      1 |      1 |    1 |
|  3 | SDGS046 |        1 | Shivaprasad |      1 |     1 |      3 |      1 |    2 |
+----+---------+----------+-------------+--------+-------+--------+--------+------+
test.sku

+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| SkuDetailsId | sku     | seller_id | itemName    | itemLength | itemWeight | itemHeight | itemWidth |
+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|            1 | Sample  |         1 | SampleItem  |          1 |      1.000 |          1 |         1 |
|            2 | Sample  |         2 | Sample1     |          1 |      1.000 |          1 |         1 |
|            3 | SDGS046 |         1 | Shivaprasad |          1 |      3.000 |          1 |         1 |
+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+

testdb.shipping_skudetails
```

now the problem is values are copied into different columns,

```
(like :  shipping_skudetails.itemWeight copied into test.width)
```

I want copy data column to column. not by arrange column in query.

> I want a query that copy data by identifying column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
INSERT INTO shyplite.sku (id, sku, sellerID, name, length, width, height, weight, mode) 
    SELECT SkuDetailsId as id, 
           sku, 
           seller_id as sellerID, 
           itemName as name, 
           itemLength as length, 
           itemWidth as width, 
           itemHeight as height, 
           itemWeight as weight, 
           modeType_id as mode
    FROM shyplitelivedb.shipping_skudetails;
```